# PhoneGap BarcodeScanner causing iOS app to hang

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, barcode

I've got a working PhoneGap app that I'm trying to add a QR scanner to. To do this, I'm using PhoneGap Build's BarcodeScanner plugin. The issue that I'm having is that upon a scan completing, an alert will cause the app to freeze.

The relevant JavaScript is

```
var options=""
options += '<p>'+formData["form"][formPart][1]+'</p>'
options += '<a data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" formPart="'+formPart+'"id="Cap-'+formPart+'">Capture Image</a>'
options += '<p id="Cap-Data"></p>'
$('#formContent').append(options);
$('#Cap-'+formPart).on("tap",function(event){
var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
scanner.scan(
 function (result) {
  var FP = $(this).attr("formPart");
  $('#Cap-Data').html(result.text);
   alert(result.text);
  }, 
  function (error) {
   alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
});
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is functions like `alert` or `prompt` stop the execution completely until they return. Try putting the alert code in `setTimeout()` No timeout needed though, you can set it to 0 ms. so it will immediately occur but won't block the flow.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  alert(result.text);
}, 0);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) might be a good read about why `setTimeout(fn, 0)` helps in these situations.

Comment: ha! iOS is the new IE6. Thanks for the fix, was my exact issue as well